# beginner question while trying useState: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: reactjs

I was just following the example for useState in the react dev website. Could someone point me in the right direction to resolve this error please? I am not sure where I am making a mistake, looks like I am missing some reference. In data.js, I am defining and exporting the array of objects sculptureList which I am destructuring and getting it out in Gallery.js. Is something wrong in this assignment?

```
let sculpture = sculptureList[index];
```

**data.js**

```
export const sculptureList = [
{
    name: 'Homenaje a la Neurocirugía',
    artist: 'Marta Colvin Andrade',
    description: 'Although Colvin is predominantly known for abstract themes that allude to pre-Hispanic symbols, this gigantic sculpture, an homage to neurosurgery, is one of her most recognizable public art pieces.',
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/Mx7dA2Y.jpg',
    alt: 'A bronze statue of two crossed hands delicately holding a human brain in their fingertips.'
},
{
    name: 'Floralis Genérica',
    artist: 'Eduardo Catalano',
    description: 'This enormous (75 ft. or 23m) silver flower is located in Buenos Aires. It is designed to move, closing its petals in the evening or when strong winds blow and opening them in the morning.',
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/ZF6s192m.jpg',
    alt: 'A gigantic metallic flower sculpture with reflective mirror-like petals and strong stamens.'
}];
```

**Gallery.js**

```
import { sculptureList } from "./data";
import { useState } from "react";

const Gallery = () => {

  const { index, setIndex } = useState(0);
 
  function handleClick(){
    setIndex(index + 1); 
  }

  let sculpture = sculptureList[index];
  console.log(sculpture);

  return (
      <>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>
              Next
          </button>
          <h2>
              <i>{sculpture.name}</i> by {sculpture.artist}
          </h2>
          <h3>{index + 1} of {sculptureList.length}</h3>
          <img src={sculpture.url} alt={sculpture.alt} />
          <p>{sculpture.description}</p>
      </>
  );
}
export default Gallery;
```

**App.js**

```
import Gallery from './Gallery';

function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">              
      <div className="content">          
        <Gallery />
      </div>        
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: does the error occur immediately or after few clicks on `next` button

Comment: It occurs immediately when I run it for the first time

Comment: and what is the result of this code `console.log(sculpture);` ?

Comment: It doesn't even get to that, I think as I only see errors and nothing else in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occur because you don't use the `useState` function correctly.

You did `const { index, setIndex } = useState(0);`

And by that you use object destructuring, but for `useState` function you must use **array destructuring**.
So just change this line of code to `const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);`

---

Also, notice that after 2 clicks on the "next" button, the error will occur again because you will exceed your data items by length.

I would add an extra safety mechanism:

```js
import { sculptureList } from "./data";
import { useState } from "react";

const Gallery = () => {

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
 
  function handleClick(){
    setIndex(index + 1); 
  }

  let sculpture = sculptureList[index];
  console.log(sculpture);

  return (
      <>
          {index <= sculptureList.length - 1 && (
                <button onClick={handleClick}>Next</button>
          )}
     
          <h2>
              <i>{sculpture.name}</i> by {sculpture.artist}
          </h2>
          <h3>{index + 1} of {sculptureList.length}</h3>
          <img src={sculpture.url} alt={sculpture.alt} />
          <p>{sculpture.description}</p>
      </>
  );
}
export default Gallery;
```

Comment: Typo related solutions are comments at best.. question could be voted to close.

Comment: How stupid of me. Thank you so much. I will accept your answer. Looks like I have to wait for a couple of minutes more.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes, but I want to add some other suggestion for future bug he might have